# Complex database normalization

Tags: database-normalization

I'm trying to set up a database for a water department's online system, keeping track of all past usage for each account/meter.
The database receives a csv file containing all of the day's readouts.
The csv's that I receive have the following data:

- Account number (may have multiple meters/addresses on one account)
- Address
- Meter ID (may have multiple ports for appartment complexes, commercial buildings, etc.)
- Port number
- Reading (numeric)
- Reading Date (string)
- Meter Serial Number (relates to meter id)
- Installation date (relates to meter id)

I was starting to think of the DB setup, and this is as far as I got:

- Meter information

  - Meter ID (primary key)
  - Meter Serial
  - Installation Date
  - Address
  - number of ports
- Meter Usage (titled my meter ID)

  - Reading Date
  - Reading

I was thinking of each meter having its own table, which is named the meter id, which would make accessing the past data for one meter easy, but brings in the problem of separating by ports.

in the following, how would I differentiate between meter# 000003's ports?
[image]

one idea was to append the port# to the end of the meter ID#
i.e. having 0000031 and 0000032

So my main problems are, dealing with a meter possibly having multiple ports and
an account possibly having multiple meters, which may have multiple ports.

This will be the first non-pseudo-database that I have set up, so any help from you guys will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do the Reading Date and Reading value relate to the port. For example for meter 0003 would it have Reading Dates for both Ports 1 and 2? If not what is the importance of ports and what do they do ?

Comment: Meter 3 port 1 can have a different value in both fields than meter 3 port 2, so yes, they are dependent on the port.  The ports will diferentiate between different apartments, where one apt complex has one meter, but many units, for example. (not sure why they set it up like that, but it's what I have to deal with)

Comment: Also, one meter can point to many accounts via its ports.

Comment: Why do you mention normalization when you show nothing re doing it? Also: This is too broad. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook. Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Ask a specific question where stuck. PS Please clarify via edits not comments.

Answer (score 1):

Going ahead with @Roger's thought process you many not need the port number if they can't be split to separate account#'s But You should have An account table With Account Number being a PK and liking to your meter table, maybe an address table, although that could get complicated if your planning on using an address table for your meter table to point to. Also if I am correct your Meter Serial numbers should be unique so you could use that for your primary key instead of creating an auto incrementing PK Also you wouldn't necessarily need a new table for every meter usage, you could simply have a MeterUsageTable With an Auto inc PK called UsageID, MeterID with the meters ID the reading date and reading and simple query's will be able to give you all your history. Although if your going to be entering a companies complete usage history it will add up to a huge amount of data.
EDIT:
I think you want your database to look something like this you can tweek what you need and don't need but here's the relationships i think you need in order to go from AccountNumber to usages
[image: Possible Solution]

Comment: So AccountNumbers will need to be linked to particular MeterID(s) and port(s)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. It comes down to - with the apartment complex, will the landlord pay the water bill, or will the tenants be billed directly.

Comment: The reason I'm thinking of seperate tables is that the main implementation of this DB is so that a user can look up their past usage, and I'm assuming that having to pick from millions of entries is a bit worse than scanning through 40k table names and grabbing all values from that table.

Comment: But going forward with Rogers Idea if Customer A Moves out of the area coverage Customer B is going to move in and take over Customer A's Meter/Port(s). You will need a way to track when the change happened. Also how will users be looking up the tables? You could have them call a stored proc with Account Number and hand them back the usage assuming there is some hook to the user. But if I have to look through 100 tables for my usage I'd get annoyed

Comment: Thats why I want the account numbers to somehow point to the meter/port. That was an issue that my boss (brother) brought up to me.  All that will need to change is the acct info table (setting a date to ignore prior readings).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment I would then suggest the following:

### accounts

### meter

id
account_id
serial_number
installation_date
address

### meter_ports

meter_id

### readings

meter_port_id
reading_date
reading

As far as address goes I am not sure if you will support multiple cities, states, zip codes. If you will, you might consider normalizing that as well to give you the ability to group on  certain zip codes, cities etc.